# Reading from a collection of modules in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm using the `lambda_function` module with `for_each` to create multiple lambdas.

I'm getting this error in a different resource when trying to assemble a policy JSON:

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid function argument
│ 
│   on main.tf line 83, in resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_policy" "staging_tables_secret":
│   83:         "AWS": "${join(",", module.lambda_function[*].lambda_role_arn)}"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.lambda_function is a map of object, known only after apply
│ 
│ Invalid value for "lists" parameter: element 0: string required.
╵

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What am I doing wrong, how am I supposed to list the role ARNs generated by the lambda module?

Here is how the module looks by the way, along with the local that gets iterated:

```
module "lambda_function" {
  for_each = { for index, value in local.application_files : index => value }

  source = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"

  source_path = "${path.module}/functions/${each.value.directory}"

  function_name = each.value.directory

  runtime = "python3.9"
  handler = "${each.value.handler_file}.lambda_handler"

  environment_variables = {
    secrets_manager_arn = aws_secretsmanager_secret.staging_tables_secret.arn
  }
}

locals {
  application_files = [
    {
      directory    = "hello1"
      handler_file = "hello1"
    },
    {
      directory    = "hello2"
      handler_file = "hello2"
    }
  ]
}
```

EDIT: here is the link to the external module I'm using: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws/latest

Comment: You're leaving out the most important part, which is the definition of the module (it appears to be something homegrown, but if it's a publicly-published module please paste a link to the source).

Comment: For that matter, what's on `main.tf line 83`? Show your _entire_ config, or reduce to a minimal config that reproduces the problem. Otherwise, the only thing that somebody can tell you is "you wrote something that couldn't be handled by Terraform or your module."

Comment: Although as a complete guess, it appears that you're trying to provide a Lambda ARN as the target of an "AWS" Principal specification, which just isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of reading [this bit in the docs about the splat expression not working with maps](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html#splat-expressions-with-maps).

Basically the solution was to use `[for v in module.lambda_function : v.lambda_role_arn]` as the sub-expression instead of `module.lambda_function[*].lambda_role_arn`.